# Date range search filter functionality in asp.net mvc 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Good evening everyone, I hope, anyone can help my with Date time range filter on view part. Here is my model:

```
public class Student
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public virtual Course Course { get; set; }
    public DateTime CurrentDate { get; set; }
    public Student()
    {
        CurrentDate = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

I'm using view models for display, now here is my controller:

```
    public ActionResult Index(DateTime? startdate, DateTime? enddate)
    {
        var rangeData = db.Students.Where(x => x.CurrentDate >= startdate && x.CurrentDate <= enddate).ToList();

        return View(rangeData);
    }
```

Now I have some problems with view as well as in controller.

Here is My QUESTION: How to pass start and end date to controller to get orders with defined properties? Here is My View and what I'm doing wrong?

```
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Students", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Search criteria</legend>
        @Html.Label("StartDate", "Start Date:")
        <input class="startdate" id="startdate" name="startdate" type="date" value="">
        @Html.Label("enddate", "End Date:")
        <input class="startdate" id="enddate" name="enddate" type="date" value="">
        <input type="submit" value="Apply" />
    </fieldset>
} 


<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.StudentName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Address)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Gender)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MobileNo)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Course)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StudentName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Address)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Gender)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MobileNo)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Course.CourseName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Comment: Why do you have 2 separate forms and the 2nd controller method. All your controls should be in one form and post to the first method. And do not create you inputs like that. Use a view models with those properties (`SearchBy`, `StartDate` etc and with a `List<Student>` property for the filtered collection

Comment: Can you please post that by code in controller and view

Comment: what is the exact problem do have in view and controller?

Comment: http://localhost:56433/Students?startdate=2017-09-14&enddate=2017-09-14
this search query is not working and retrieving data

Comment: you can try take parameter as string after convert string into proper format as specified its problem with format for that reason parameter takes null value i think am i right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Providing a placeholder attribute to your input fields to guide user on the date format expected is one option you can use since this seems like a date format issues. Another option is to use a date picker control which will automatically set the date in the right format.

However, if you want to give your users the flexibility to input date in any format of their choice with any separator including "/",  "-" or just space, here is some tip

```
      public ActionResult Index(string startdate = null, string enddate = null)
    {
        if (startdate != null && enddate != null)
        {
            //this will default to current date if for whatever reason the date supplied by user did not parse successfully

            DateTime start = DateManager.GetDate(startdate) ?? DateTime.Now;

            DateTime end = DateManager.GetDate(enddate) ?? DateTime.Now;

            var rangeData = db.Students.Where(x => x.CurrentDate >= start && x.CurrentDate <= end).ToList();

            return View(rangeData);
        }
        return View();
    }


      public class DateManager
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Use to prevent month from being overritten when day is less than or equal 12
        /// </summary>
      static  bool IsMonthAssigned { get; set; }



        public static DateTime? GetDate(string d)
        {
            char[] splitsoptions = { '/', '-', ' ' };
            foreach (var i in splitsoptions)
            {
                var y = 0;
                var m = 0;
                var day = 0;
                if (d.IndexOf(i) > 0)
                {
           try{
                    foreach (var e in d.Split(i))
                    {


                        if (e.Length == 4)
                        {
                            y = Convert.ToInt32(e);

                            continue;
                        }
                        if (Convert.ToInt32(e) <= 12 && !IsMonthAssigned)
                        {
                            m = Convert.ToInt32(e);
                            IsMonthAssigned = true;
                            continue;
                        }
                        day = Convert.ToInt32(e);


                    }

                    return new DateTime(y, m, day);
            }catch
           { 
            //We are silent about this but we  could set a message about wrong date input in ViewBag    and display to user if this  this method returns null
            }
                }
            }
            return null;


        }
   // Another overload. this will catch more date formats without manually checking as above

     public static DateTime? GetDate(string d, bool custom)
        {
            CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");

            string[] dateFormats =
            {
                "dd/MM/yyyy", "MM/dd/yyyy", "yyyy/MM/dd", "yyyy/dd/MM", "dd-MM-yyyy", "MM-dd-yyyy", "yyyy-MM-dd",
                "yyyy-dd-MM", "dd MM yyyy", "MM dd yyyy", "yyyy MM dd", "yyyy dd MM", "dd.MM.yyyy", "MM.dd.yyyy",
                "yyyy.MM.dd", "yyyy.dd.MM","yyyyMMdd","yyyyddMM","MMddyyyy","ddMMyyyy"
            };//add your own to the array if any

            culture.DateTimeFormat.SetAllDateTimePatterns(dateFormats, 'Y');

            if (DateTime.TryParseExact(d, dateFormats, culture, DateTimeStyles.None, out var date))
                return date;

            return null;


        }
    }
```

Comment: Displaying information like "Showing result for "Select date range" will enable the user to see the date as captured in the server since this solution could conflict month and day when day is less than or equals 12